# Diamond Patter Java using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having some problems understanding how the recursion works and i have this question asking me to print a diamond pattern using recursion. after a while i got to something close to the solution i think but my output is this:

```
* * * * * * 
 * * * * * 
  * * * * 
   * * * 
    * * 
     * 
     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  * * * * 
 * * * * * 
* * * * * *
```

when it should be this:

```
     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  * * * * 
 * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
 * * * * * 
  * * * * 
   * * * 
    * * 
     *
```

```
public class DiamondPattern {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        diamond(6, 6);
    }

    public static void repeatlyPrint(int amount, String pattern) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            // print a pattern once
            System.out.print(pattern);
            // recursively call the function itself
            repeatlyPrint(amount - 1, pattern);
        }
    }

    public static void diamond(int totalHeight, int currentRow) {
        printSpaces(totalHeight - currentRow); // print spaces (outside of diamond)

        repeatlyPrint(currentRow , "* "); // print asterisks and spaces
        System.out.println();

        if (currentRow > 1) {
            diamond(totalHeight, currentRow -1);
        }

        printSpaces(totalHeight - currentRow); // print spaces
        repeatlyPrint( currentRow, "* "); // print asterisks and spaces
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void printSpaces(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

i found a question really similar with a good explanation but i'm still really confuse that's why i'm opening this question, please close if not allow but i'm really stuck.

if someone can lead me in the right direction on where am i going wrong here would be great.

Comment: divide and conquer your problem, draw the top triangle then the down triangle: think in that manner. to see code [go here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-print-diamond-shape/).

Comment: Why pass 6 as the first argument of the currentRow? That's causing zero spaces to be printed first

Answer (score 0):

When `printSpaces(totalHeight - currentRow);` is executed the first time, the argument will be 0. That means the first output will have no spaces before the first asterisk. Yet you want *the most* spaces in the first line of the output.

So, you should have `currentRow` equal to 1 instead of 6, and have it *increment* as you recur, not *decrement*.

So fix the initial call to:

```
        diamond(6, 1);
```

And fix the `diamond` function near the recursive call:

```
        if (currentRow < 6) { // Changed condition
            diamond(totalHeight, currentRow + 1); // increase
        }
```